# pod/container name resolution does not work outside containers

Tags: kubernetes

I am able to resolve pod names to ip addresses inside the corresponding containers, e.g. if I have a pod called `elasticsearch-0` and I enter the container via `kubectl exec -it elasticsearch-0 bash` I can do the following:

```
curl elasticsearch-0:9200
```

and get the response:

```
{
  "name" : "OUvCoFL",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "1Vhf2-pGR0m3e4ezDRAZ0Q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "c0c1ba0",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-12T12:32:54.550Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

However, if I try to do this from within a different container, e.g. kibana-0, it fails with:

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: elasticsearch-0; Name or service not known`

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) in place?

Comment: `curl elasticsearch-0:9200` worked inside that container. Because `HOSTNAME` of that container is elasticsearch. Across containers(across pods), we have to use `service`. Across containers(in same pod), we can use `localhost` to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service is what you are looking for. Read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#the-kubernetes-model-for-connecting-containers)

> Pods can be configured to talk to the Service, and know that communication to the Service will be automatically load-balanced out to some pod that is a member of the Service.

Create the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
```

And [access](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#accessing-the-service) the service from any pod

`curl http://elasticsearch:9200`